# how to catch a failwith with nUnit in F#?

Tags: f#, nunit

let's assume I have this code:

```
let a () =
    failwith "I want to fail!"
```

and then I have a nUnit test:

```
Assert.Throws(fun () -> a() |> ignore)
```

the test will return:

> Method has non-void return value, but no result is expected
> Exception doesn't have a stacktrace

How can I test cases where I have an expected failwith situation?

There are a few questions / answers regarding exceptions, but I didn't find an answer for the failwith case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 Assert.Throws(typeof<System.Exception>, TestDelegate (a)) |> ignore
```

On a side note you may want to try [*FsUnit*](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/) a more friendly framework on top of NUnit.  The code would look like this:

```
   (fun () -> a() |> ignore)
   |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
Assert.Throws(fun () -> a() |> ignore)
```

The `ignore` applies to the function you are testing, not to `Assert.Throws`. That's no doubt what you intended and is correct.

However, `Assert.Throws` - unlike most nunit Assertions - actually returns a value: the exception that  was thrown. You could probably ignore that as well...

```
Assert.Throws(fun () -> a() |> ignore) |> ignore
```

Usually, you would not want to ignore the return, however. The whole point of returning it is that you may want to verify the message, look at the stacktrace, etc. If I didn't want to do anything but assert that some exception was thrown, I would normally use

```
Assert.That(fun () -> a() |> ignore, Throws.Exception);
```

Assert.That returns C# void, aka `unit`.

[All of this is forum code, as I don't have F# installed on this machine. YMMV.]